# how to add external proxy on routing apis of zuul

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, proxy, netflix-zuul

I need to add external proxy to the routing API as it's giving SSL error.
Just like creating custom resttemplate as follow:

```
 SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("abc.xyz.com", 80));
requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);

return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

Custom resttemplate is working and not giving error, but I need to redirect API in Zuul. I am not able to understand how to set proxies and port.

```
@Override
public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    String remoteHost = ctx.getRequest().getRemoteHost();
    String requestURL = ctx.getRequest().getRequestURL().toString();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to use Zuul to proxy inner http calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48867045/is-there-a-way-to-use-zuul-to-proxy-inner-http-calls)